# python: Accessing variable in functions in different modules

Tags: python, variables, global, local

I've distilled down what I'm trying to do to the simplest form. I have a one module (prog1.py) that runs fine. A function in prog1.py accesses a variable (yy) OK without an error.

```
#prog1.py 
def func():
    print (yy)
    return()

def main(yy):
    print(yy)
    func()
    return()

#-----------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':     
    yy = 200
    main(yy)
```

When I import that module into another module (prog2.py) the same function cannot access the variable (yy).

```
#prog2.py
import prog1
yy = 200
prog1.main(yy)
```

I get:

> name 'yy' is not defined in line 3 in func.

What is the "correct" (python) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in `func`:

```
def func():
    print (yy)
    return()
```

Line `print (yy)` tries to access `yy`, but `if __name__ == '__main__':` will not be true for that module (`__name__` will be `prog1` not `__main__`), hence it will not go inside `if`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':     
    yy = 200
    main(yy)
```

Hence `yy` will not be defined.

Read more about `if __name__ == '__main__':` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

---

According to what you have mentioned in the comments:

```
#prog1.py

yy = 'prog1 yy'


def func():
    print(yy)


def main(yy):
    print(yy)
    func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    yy = 200
    main(yy)
```

```
# prog2.py

import prog1


yy = 200
prog1.main(yy)
```

Run:

```
python prog2.py
```

Output:

```
200
prog1 yy
```

Comment: I understand, but `yy` is defined in the `main(yy)` routine as the print works. The problem only occurs when `func` tries to use `yy`.

Comment: We have passed `yy` to the `main` function, hence it can access it (scope of `yy` is limited to `main`, `func` doesn't know about it). You have to explicitly pass it as a parameter to `func`, so that it can access it (similar to what you did to `main`).

Comment: OK thanks Dipen, but I was trying to do it without resorting to passing `yy` as a parameter. Is `global` the way to go? Although I gather some people say not to use it.

Comment: Yes, using a global variable it is possible, but whenever possible, we should try to avoid global variables.

Comment: I did try using global but still got the error. Can you indicate how to use global in the situation I described?

Comment: Updated the answer! Please check!